# Unable to send HTTPS request

Tags: c#, .net, https, .net-core

I have to send an HTTPS POST request.
I created a library class to send the HTTPS POST request.
I have 2 programs calling this library class:

- My main program (IdentityServer)
- My test class

Both programs only call the library class with the given arguments (to be used on POST body) and the library class performs the request.

The problem is that, when running this on my test class it works fine. However with IdentityServer it throws the following error "System.Net.Http.WinHttpException".

The only difference I note between the test class and IdentityServer is their 'target framework':

- IdentityServer (.NET Core 2.0)
- Test Class (.NET Framework 4.6.1)
- Class Library (.NET Framework 4.6.1)

And this is my simple code to send the request:

```
public static async Task<HttpStatusCode> Send(String destination, String message, String accountUsername, String accountPassword, String senderPhoneNumber)
    {

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "username", accountUsername },
            { "password", accountPassword },
            { "src", senderPhoneNumber },
            { "dst", destination },
            { "text", message },
            { "srr", "3" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        HttpStatusCode responseStatus = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable;

        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            ServicePointManager
                .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            var response = await client.PostAsync("TARGET_URL", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseStatus = response.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            string error = we.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = e.ToString();
        }
        return responseStatus;
    }
```

I ignore the certificate from the target server since their certificate is invalid.

But, as I said, it works just fine calling this with my test class.

The complete error thrown when calling from IdentityServer is the following:

```
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VdfnHungSMSLibrary.VdfnHungSMSProvider.<Send>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\IdentityServer\Current\src\VdfnHungSMSLibrary\VdfnHungSMSProvider.cs:line 43
```

Comment: Can you talk us through what `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;` is there for?

Comment: Otherwise it won't work and will trow the following exception:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Would not work even with test class...

Comment: @RicardoAlmeida I had an similar experience with that and I saw this _ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;_ as a solution in some forums too. Do you own the service that you're trying to invoke? Can you update the minimum security protocol of it? In my case that was the correction instead of set the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the service. And I found that solution too, by setting only 'Tls'. And it works, but only with my test class calling my library class. When it is my IdentityServer it ignores that ServicePointManager...